# Ruby on Rails function defined failed tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined a function that takes in a number and returns true if it is a
power of 2. Otherwise, return false:

```
def is_power_of_two?(num)
  n = 0
  res = false
  if num % 2 == 0
    while 2^n <= num
      if 2^n == num
        res = true
      end
      n += 1
    end 
  end
  puts(n.to_s)
  return res
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts('is_power_of_two?(1) == true: ' + (is_power_of_two?(1) == true).to_s)
puts('is_power_of_two?(16) == true: ' + (is_power_of_two?(16) == true).to_s)
puts('is_power_of_two?(64) == true: ' + (is_power_of_two?(64) == true).to_s)
puts('is_power_of_two?(78) == false: ' + (is_power_of_two?(78) == false).to_s)
puts('is_power_of_two?(0) == false: ' + (is_power_of_two?(0) == false).to_s)
```

However, my test results turn out to fail four out of five:

```
0                                                                                                                                                                                      
is_power_of_two?(1) == true: false                                                                                                                                                     
16                                                                                                                                                                                     
is_power_of_two?(16) == true: false                                                                                                                                                    
64                                                                                                                                                                                     
is_power_of_two?(64) == true: false                                                                                                                                                    
77                                                                                                                                                                                     
is_power_of_two?(78) == false: false                                                                                                                                                   
0                                                                                                                                                                                      
is_power_of_two?(0) == false: true
```

The result printed out seems to match what's expected, however, the tests still failed. Does anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you expecting ^ to calculate the power then that is wrong ^ is XOR to calculate power use **

```
2^2 # 0
2**2 # 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You always want to check if it is true that it is a power of two, this way it returns false when it is not a power of two.

This feels like a homework question so I'm not going to give you the exact answer, but this should nudge you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

As  mohamed-ibrahm says, you're using the wrong operator.

The caret is a bitwise XOR operation.  So `2^3 == 1` (because decimal 2 is 010 in binary and decimal 3 is 011 in binary and as all bits are the same except the last, the result is 001 or decimal 1).

Exponentiation is done by double asterisks, so `2**3 == 8`

Here's a description of the various operators.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm